# is it possible to use GCC with Visual Studio Code IDE, like it uses the debugger GDB

Tags: gcc

The new Visual Studio Code IDE for cross platform.
Is it possible to create a task which can handle a makefile like operation and thereby build a c++ project ??

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin: makeRunner, which will start a build using;
 make -f Makefile, and it seems pt. no plans for VSCode to have embedded compiler/linker